# Python - I can't use function display in pycharm

Tags: python

I can use the function display() to see my excel data just fine on google colabs or jupyter, but can't use it on pycharm and have to use print instead. Why is that?

Comment: Have you called JetBrains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Display is a module which is a part of IPython. Jupyter notebooks run the IPython kernel to execute code.

Pycharm on the other hand is just an IDE, which is completely unrelated to IPython.

In other words, the display() function isn't part of the python STL, it's just something that IPython provides, which is why you can use this function in Jupyter Notebooks.

Comment: For the record, [Pycharm can run IPython](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/ipython.html) so saying it's *completely unrelated* is a bit of an over-statement...